# Why does posting form with ajax plugin give result in console but not post the form to the server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am using a plugin to hijack a form and post it via an ajax function within the plugin. I can post the form and get a result in the console but I am unable to get the form to post and work properly.

My current build is using:

Laravel - PHP framework
Instagram PHP class - Interacting with the instagram api with php
Ajax plugin - To post forms without page refresh.

Currently I have got this for the ajax code(plugin):

[Link here](http://pastebin.com/zsv9iVcD)

And in my functions.js file I have got this code to post the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.forms').each(function() {

        $(this).formSubmit({

                // Shows the formData that will be submitted; return false 
                // to prevent the form from being submitted
                before: function(formData) {
                    if( console ) {
                        console.log('`before` callback:');
                        console.log(formData);
                    }
                },

                // Shows the AJAX response when the form is accepted
                success: function(data) {
                    if( console ) {
                        console.log('`success` callback:');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },

                // Shows the AJAX response when the form is rejected
                error: function(data) {
                    if( console ) {
                        console.log('`error` callback:');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },

                // Shows the AJAX error if one occurs
                ajaxError: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if( console ) {
                        console.log('`ajaxError` callback:');
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                },

                // These add and remove a custom class called 'whoops' to the 
                // parent element of all invalid fields
                showInvalid: function() {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('whoops');
                },
                hideInvalid: function() {
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('whoops');
                }

            });

    });
});
```

Below is the markup for the form that wraps around the image so you can send a like/unlike through the instagram api from the form submit.

```
try {

    $instagram = new Instagram\Instagram;

    $instagram->setAccessToken($_SESSION['instagram_access_token']);
    $token = $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'];
    //$clientID = $_SESSION['client_id'];

    $current_user = $instagram->getCurrentUser();
    $tag = $instagram->getTag('folkclothing');
    $media = $tag->getMedia(isset($_GET['max_tag_id']) ? array( 'max_tag_id' => $_GET['max_tag_id'] ) : null);


    $liked_media = $current_user->getLikedMedia();
    /* echo 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'. $item->getId() .'/likes?access_token='.$token.''; */

    if ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) ) {

    echo '<br/>FORM IS SUBMITTED, INSPECT WHAT WAS SENT';        
        print_r($_POST);

        $id = $_POST['id'];

                switch( strtolower( $_POST['action'] ) ) {
            case 'like':
                $current_user->addLike( $id );
                break;
            case 'unlike':
                $current_user->deleteLike( $id );
                break;
                }
       }

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // yes there is an error
    $error = $e->getMessage();

}


echo '<section id="images">';

foreach ( $media as $item ) {

    echo '<article class="instagram-image">';
    echo '<form class="forms" action="'; echo URL::current(); echo '" method="post">';

        $id = $item->getId();

        echo '<a title="' . $item->getCaption() .'" class="fancybox" href="' . $item->link . '"><img alt="' . $item->getCaption() .'" src="' . $item->images->standard_resolution->url . '" /></a>';
        echo '<div class="formSubmit-feedback"></div>';
        echo '<img src="/public/img/377.gif" alt="loader"/>';
        if ( $current_user->likes($item) ){
            echo '<button class="ajax instabtn unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>';
        } else {
            echo '<button class="ajax instabtn like icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Like"></button>';
        }
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'; echo $id; echo '">';

        echo '<p>'; echo $item->likes->count; echo '</p>';

    echo '</form>';
    echo '</article>';
}
echo '</section>';
```

The errors I get when posting the form are below, it finds the right id of the object to post tobut it will not post to the server:

```
`before` callback: functions.js:51
Object {id: "509073517011482478_5670460"}
```

I know its close but I am unsure where to look with it.

Comment: Did I read this too fast?  It shows all of your status functions as posting to `console.log`.  You will need to change your `before`, `success`, etc. to actually do the post.

Comment: Okay, if I wanted to post with the success function then its just like a normal ajax post right? Just pass in the form data?

Comment: It seems like you don't even have an ajax post anywhere.  When you make an ajax post, you will use those statuses in your post.  Check this out : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  Read up on AJAX and find a place for the call.  Then when you get stuck, come place another question

Comment: That's not an error, that's the log you set up for the before event of the ajax call, do you get any other messages in the console? check the network tab of your browser's dev tools and analyze the ajax call

Comment: The Ajax call goes through and works because in the header tab you can see the form id in it. Do you think it could be the Ajax plugin that is not passing to the right URL?